# Is there any option for small size sample of PCA

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, small-sample

I have 73 sample size and 18 variables. Could I have to any way to perform PCA analysis for those data?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot apply PCA to your data?

Comment: I was studied about pca where many author strongly and strictly preferred to sample size should be atleast 100 and variable minimum 18 where SVT ratio can be 5:1.  There I got confusion to perform pca that it will be valid or not!

Comment: Please give me any link or anything that I can perform PCA for those data with valid way

Comment: This is the first I have seen those guidelines. If you want to follow them, then there is no way to do PCA in a way that is “valid” according to those guidelines. However, the matrix algebra will work out fine. You will get your eigenvectors, eigenvalues, and diagonal matrix.

Comment: I just wanted to know that,  is my data enough to perform PCA or not?

Comment: In what sense? You have enough for the equations to work. You lack enough to be able to do much, but that’s kind of how it goes when you try to do complicated modeling with $73$ observations.

Comment: I think you confuse finding a solution with PCA for data reduction with finding a stable solution such as in factor analysis, which is expected to arise again in an independent dataset.

Comment: Yes! I want that as a right way

Comment: For PCA, you can even do it with n (sample size)<p (number of features). But for factor analysis or PCA used as factor analysis (i.e. w/ the prospect to interpret the PCs as latent variables responsible for the correlations) n/p should be at least 5 if n is small (say, below 100). 73/18 might be considered tolerable, but if you want factor analysis, do _it_, and not "PCA as factor analysis".